# same limit for subsequence and sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $(x_n \in \mathbb{Z})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\lim_n x_n = +\infty$.

Then, take a particular subsequence $b_m = x_{n_m}$ and given $\lim f(b_m) = K$,

how do I show that $\lim f(x_n) = K$ ?

**EDIT: Nevermind.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $f(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}2x)$, $x_n = n$, and $b_m = 2m$.

Answer (score 1):

What if $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \{b_m\}$, and $0$ otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. For example, let $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is even, and $1$ if $x$ is odd. Then, take the sequence $\{x_n\} = 1,2,...$ . We have $\lim_n x_n = +\infty$, and for $b_m = 2,4,6,...$ we have $\lim_m f(b_m) = 0$, however $\lim_n f(x_n)$ does not exist.

Note : If $f(t) = |\sin \frac{\pi t}2|$ for example, then we see that $f$ takes the desired values , and is continuous on $\mathbb R$, so the property does not hold even under continuity of $f$. The reason for this is that even if $f$ is continuous, the limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ need not exist, because $\infty$ is not a real number(subtle point). If the limit does not exist, we may still have various limit points , as is shown here.